# Vuejs get session once its set

Tags: vue.js

I am setting session in my login function

```
 router.app.$session.set('user', user);
```

I am trying to retrieve it in the function which loads after login

```
router.app.$session.get('user');
```

Its giving undefined. If I delay the session.get function by few seconds, I am able to get the value.

Is there any alternative way to get session value except delay?

Comment: Vue.nextTick? [api](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

Comment: is the login function making an asyc call to an external api and are you setting the session in a callback? that would explain the problem.

Comment: @phoet I am setting the session in the login function. Once logged In, user will be directed to home page and here under created() I need the session value. I have async but it still returns undefined.